# why confirmation message box is not coming only in IE and safari, on static pdf pages(Extjs4.1)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have done application using Extjs 4, In app some places showcasing statis pdf pages. in this app given option to user, he can logout from any pages. If i am in static pdf screen, once i click here logout button. it will show confirmation box to logout. This one is working very nice in mozila and chrome but problem is coming only in IE and safari. In IE and safari click of logout button, screen it self does some action not able to see confirmation message box on pdf page may be i think it is going behind of the pdf. Can anybody tell me how resolve this issue? great appreciated. Thank you.

**Here is my code:**

```
onbtnLogoutClick: function(){
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to Logout?', function(btn){
        if (btn == 'yes'){
           Ext.getCmp('mainContainer').removeAll();
           Ext.getCmp('mainContainer').insert(0,{xtype:'loginView'});

   }  
  }
}
```

**Here is my sample code, showcasing pdf's**

```
 {        
    xtype: 'panel',
    frame: true,
    height: window.innerHeight-100,
    html: '<iframe width="100%" height="95%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src='MypdfUrl'></iframe>'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it should work. check in developer tool(IE), whether component reference has been created or not.

Try for alternative ext class of show.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
     title:'Save Changes?',
     msg: '<your mes>',
     buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
     fn: processResult,
     animateTarget: 'elId',
     icon: Ext.window.MessageBox.QUESTION
});
```

Thanks

Comment: No i have applied this one. it is also not working, message box itself not showing anything to option like select ok/cancel/yes/no. is there any other way? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but let think about **html**

```
 {        
   xtype: 'panel',
   frame: true,
   height: window.innerHeight-100,
   html: '' /*Becos some of html tags string makes Extjs error! within IE*/
 }
```

if html ='' i think it will work.